# Asp.NET Core, HTML helper works but not Tag helper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working with validation (Identity framework) and the Tag helpers have worked so far in the file in question but, in order to show the errors during the log in the Tag helpers don't seem to be working, while the HTML one works and the errors are properly shown.

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
```

I also tried: `asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly"` and `asp-validation-summary="All"`

This works however:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">
    <div class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationSummary()</div>
```

So, what am I missing?

Also, the `class="text-danger"` is not working since the text appears in black instead of red.

Comment: This code looks fine to me. You are saying text appears on black. That means you are seeing the validation errors ? Then which part is not working ?

Comment: Did you included validationscripts partial? Or the jquery.validation library?

Comment: @Shyju The text appears in black when the HTML helper is used. With the tag helpers nothing appears

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak Can you explain better? I have no idea what the validationsscipts partial or jquery.validation library are and that i needed to include them

Comment: Take a look at the `Views/Account/Login.cshtml` view. Way bottom, on the last row you'll find this `await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");`. Put this also in your view, exactly as it is in this one.

Comment: i'm doing a .net project from scratch and I still don't have `Login.cshtml`. Are you talking about the `Login.cshtml` default of a Web app?